# Long division for multipolynomial expression, little o notation

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, fractions, irreducible-polynomials

I have this expression:

$$\mathrm{Exp}=\frac{d^3(-12a^4)+d^2(4a^4-16a^3)+d(4a^3-6a^2-a)}{d^3(-12a^4+12a^3)+d^2(4a^4-20a^3+16a^2)+d(4a^3-11a+7a)+(1-2a+a^2)}$$

Is there any way I can take the second term and do long division or something so it becomes

$$\mathrm{Exp}=+f(d)+f(d^2)+o(d^3)$$

where $o(d^3)$ is the little $o$ notation? I can't seem to find a way to do this (Matlab and otherwise). Thank you so much!

Comment: "Anyway" is a perfectly respectable word but not synonymous with "any way" (two words). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Are you certain it is not $1/(1-a) + f(d) + o(a)$ instead ?

Comment: @Circonflexe You mean that the f(d) and o(d) is in the denominator? No, I'm fairly sure I want them in the numerator as I want them to be a correction term to the $1/(1-a)$ term.

Comment: Dialogue of the deafs here :-) I meant $\frac{1}{1-a}+f(d)+o(a)$. **Note that this is $a$, not $d$.** Your expression $\frac{1}{1-a}+f(d)+o(d)$ does not depend on $a$. (Unless $a$ is a parameter? In which case, your question becomes much simpler, as you simply need to perform long division in the field $K[d]$, where $K$ is the field $\mathbb Q(a)$). Oh, and remove the $1/(1-a)$ already from your expression, it is only confusing people here.

Comment: @Circonflexe I have corrected the problem as you stated.

Comment: @circonflexe (Sorry, I completely missed the o(a) that you wrote).  No, I really meant o(d) [or o(d^3)]  I treat 'a' as a constant, but I get lost when I do the long division... From the fraction I want to extract the f(d), f(d^2) etc and to get a simplication to the original fraction